# Set Intersect line for multiple ranges is too long

Tags: excel, vba

The below code will not work because the `Set isect` line is too long and I cannot figure out how to make it a multiple line code.  I have tried space `(_)` and enter.

If I make the line multiple lines starting with `Set isect = Application.Intersect (Target, Range ())` it will only work on the last line of code.

The intent of the Excel sheet is to make a popup requiring data input if the selected cell has no as an answer.  The required remarks would go into the cell to the right.

How do I split the `Set isect` line into multiple lines?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim com As String
Dim comm1 As String
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C14, C21:C47, F10:F14, F21:F47, I10:I14, I21:I47, L10:L14, L21:L47, O10:O14, O21:O47, r10:R14, r21:R47, U10:U14, U21:U47, X10:X14, X21:X47, AA10:AA14, AA21:AA47, AD10:AD14, AD21:AD47, AG10:AG14, AG21:AG47, AJ10:AJ14, AJ21:AJ47, AM10:AM14, AM21:AM47, AP10:AP14, AP21:AP47, AS10:AS14, AS21:AS47, AV10:AV14, AV21:AV47, AY10:AY14, AY21:AY47, BB10:BB14, BB21:BB47, BE10:BE14, BE21:BE47, BH10:BH14, BH21:BH47, BK10:BK14, BK21:BK47, BN10:BN14, BN21:BN47, BQ10:BQ14, BQ21:BQ47, BT10:BT14, BT21:BT47, BW10:BW14, BW21:BW47, BZ10:BZ14, BZ21:BZ47, CC10:CC14, CC21:CC47, CF10:CF14, CF21:CF47, CI10:CI14, CI21:CI47, CL10:CL14, CL21:CL47, CO10:CO14, CO21:CO47, CR10:CR14, CR21:CR47, CU10:CU14, CU21:CU47, CX10:CX14, CX21:CX47, DA10:DA14, DA21:DA47, DA10:DA14, DA21:DA47, DD10:DD14, DD21:DD47, DG10:DG14, DG21:DG47, DJ10:DJ14, DJ21:DJ47, DM10:DM14, DM21:DM47, DP10:DP14, DP21:DP47, DS10:DS14, DS21:DS47, DV10:DV14, DV21:DV47, DY10:DY14, DY21:DY47, EB10:EB14, EB21:EB47, EE10:EE14, EE21:
EE47 , EH10: EH14 , EH21: EH47 , EK10: EK14 , EK21: EK47 , EN10: EN14 , EN21: EN47 , EQ10: EQ14 , EQ21: EQ47 , ET10: ET14 , ET21: ET47 "))"
If isect Is Nothing Then

Else

 If Target.Value = "No" Then
     com = "Enter comment in " & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)

     Do While comm1 = ""
        comm1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:=com, Type:=2)
        On Error GoTo myloop
        If comm1 = False Then
            comm1 = ""
        End If
myloop:
     On Error GoTo -1
     Loop
     Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = comm1

 Else
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
 End If

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to skin this cat.

The easiest but least sustainable way to do what you're doing is to simply break up the line across rows.

```
Dim strRange As String

strRange = "C10:C14, C21:C47, F10:F14, F21:F47, I10:I14, I21:I47, L10:L14, L21:L47, O10:O14, O21:O47, r10:R14, r21:R47, U10:U14, U21:U47, X10:X14"
strRange = strRange & ", X21:X47, AA10:AA14, AA21:AA47, AD10:AD14, AD21:AD47, AG10:AG14, AG21:AG47, AJ10:AJ14, AJ21:AJ47, AM10:AM14, AM21:AM47, AP10:AP14"
strRange = strRange & ", AP21:AP47, AS10:AS14, AS21:AS47, AV10:AV14, AV21:AV47, AY10:AY14, AY21:AY47, BB10:BB14, BB21:BB47, BE10:BE14, BE21:BE47"
strRange= strRange & ... etc.

set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range(strRange))
```

... or you could create a named range within your workbook with all of those cells contained within it and then simply reference that in your code.

It keeps the maintenance of the range and the code separate, might not be for you though.

```
set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("ValidateRange"))
```

Another way, looking at your cells, is to create an array and a loop (which could be enhanced to be even better) so that it's building the string up with an element of dynamicness.

```
Dim strRange As String, arrColumns(), i As Long, strCol As String

arrColumns = Array("C", "F", "I", "L", etc ...)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrColumns)
    If i > 0 Then strRange = strRange & ","

    strCol = arrColumns(i)

    strRange = strRange & strCol & "10:" & strCol & "14," & strCol & "21:" & strCol & "47"
Next

Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range(strRange))
```

Like I said, there are a few ways to do what you're wanting to do.  If you're not wanting anything too complicated then go for the first solution.

I hope it helps.